# Error with admin firebase: "admin.auth(...).generatePasswordResetLink is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I made a email servies via Node.js(nodemailer) and firebase.

When I craete new new user in application, that new user should get welcome email with Link for reseting password.

Now I need to implement firebase admin --generatePasswordResetLink into node.js

> In this line of code is problem, errors is that generatePasswordResetLink() is not a function:
>
> admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(user.email, actionCodeSettings)

```
// Create user
async function createUser(user) {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      displayName: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`
    })
// After user is created make a email teamplate and send it
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      let resetLink = ''    
      // Welcome email template
      const output = `
        <p>You have access to the Church Mutual Assignment Tool.</p>
        <p>Follow this link to create new password for your account ${userRecord.email}:</p>
        <p>${this.resetLink}</p>
        <p>Thanks,</p>
        <p>Your Church Mutual Assignment Tool team</p>
      `
      let message = {
        from: 'nyik6nntutmq3vz6@ethereal.email',
        to: `${user.email}`,
        subject: 'Welcome to the Church Mutual Assignment Tool',
        text: 'Plaintext version of the message',
        html: output
      }


      // Generate reset password and Send Email
 //===== HERE IS PROBLEM THIS generatePasswordResetLink() "is not a fucntion"====== \\
      admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(user.email, actionCodeSettings)
        .then(link => {
          // Send Email
          transport.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
            if (err) throw new Error('Error with email', err)
          })
          return sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(user.email, user.displayName, link)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error', error)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What is `admin`?

Comment: admin is "const admin = require('firebase-admin')"

Comment: Do a `console.log(admin.auth())` to see if the `generatePasswordResetLink()` is in there, but based on the error it seems that is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most probably using a version of the Node.js Admin SDK that is < Version 6.2.0.

See the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK Release Notes here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node. The "email action link generation APIs for creating links for password reset, email verification and email link sign-in" were only added in November 2018, with Version 6.2.0.